How to pass 'className' as a props when using styled-components?
I have made a modal component with 'react-modal' and 'styled-components' library. I want this modal component can get another css styles and mix with its default css.
import ReactModal from 'react-modal'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledReactModal = styled(ReactModal)`
  // default styles
`

export default function BasicModal({isOpen, closeModal, children, ...restProps}: Props) {
  return (
    <StyledReactModal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onRequestClose={closeModal}
      {...restProps}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledReactModal>
  )
}

Problem
the problem is, this ReactModal component has two className properties. one is 'className' for modal component, and the other one is 'overlayClassName' for its wrapper component(usually used for dimmed background).
so I can not put imported css directly in StyledReactModal's css because overlayClassName, and overriding overlayClassName in ReactModal component is not possible with styled component because styled-component combines a style to an html element.
what I did before..
css method in 'styled-components' doesn't work...
// ...
const defaultCss = css`
  color: red;
`

const defaultOverlayCss = css`
  background-color: blue;
`

export default function BasicModal({isOpen, closeModal, children, ...restProps}: Props) {
  return (
    <StyledReactModal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onRequestClose={closeModal}
      className={defaultCss} // Error TS2769: Type FlattenSimpleInterpolation is not assignable to type string | Classes | undefined
      overlayClassName={defaultOverlayCss}
      {...restProps}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledReactModal>
  )
}

nor put a string itself doesn't work...
// ...
export default function BasicModal({isOpen, closeModal, children, ...restProps}: Props) {
  return (
    <StyledReactModal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onRequestClose={closeModal}
      className="color: red;"
      overlayClassName="background-color: blue;"
      {...restProps}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledReactModal>
  )
}

